# Symfony2+Behat+Mink: how should I refactor?

Tags: symfony, cucumber, bdd

in this [tutorial](http://docs.behat.org/cookbook/bdd_in_symfony2_with_behat_mink_and_zombiejs.html) is proposed this file system:

```
XXXBundle
   |---Features
   |      |----FeaturesContext.php
   |---ProductCategoryRelation.feature
```

where FeaturesContext.php is the file that stores the functions

```
//FeaturesContext.php
/**
 * Feature context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends BehatContext
{
  /**
   * @Given /I have a category "([^"]*)"/
   */
  public function iHaveACategory($name)
  {
      $category = new \Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Category();
      $category->setName($name);
  ...
```

And inside ProductCategoryRelation.feature is proposed to write the features and the scenarios:

```
Feature: Product Category Relationship
  In order to setup a valid catalog
  As a developer
  I need a working relationship

This being the feature, we now need the scenarios to be defined.

Scenario: A category contains a product
  Given I have a category "Underwear"
  ...
```

But if my app is growing up, how should refactor for example FeaturesContext.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use subcontexts to split step definitions into multiple context classes: http://docs.behat.org/guides/4.context.html#using-subcontexts